# How to get IP address of the server that HttpWebRequest connected to?

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, dns, ip

DSN can return multiple IP addresses so rather then using DNS resolving to get the IP address after my request I want to get the IP that my HttpWebRequest connected to.

Is there anyway to do this in .NET 3.5?

For example when I do a simple web request to www.microsoft.com I want to learn that which IP address it connected to send the HTTP request, I want to this programmatically (*not via Wireshark etc.*)

Answer (score 5):

This is a working example:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

class Program
{
    public static void Main ()
    {
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = null;
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
        req.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = delegate (ServicePoint servicePoint, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, int retryCount) {
            remoteEP = remoteEndPoint;
            return null;
        };
        req.GetResponse ();
        Console.WriteLine (remoteEP.Address.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

here you go

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.microsoft.com");
            req.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = new BindIPEndPoint(BindIPEndPoint1);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static IPEndPoint BindIPEndPoint1(ServicePoint servicePoint, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, int retryCount)
        {
            string IP = remoteEndPoint.ToString();
            return remoteEndPoint;
        }
```

Use remoteEndPoint to collect the data you want.

Comment: Is there any reason for creating a WebProxy?

Comment: Secondly won't returning remoteEndPoint will fail? As I read BindIPEndPointDelegate is used for binding a local IP address, if you return remoteEndPoint, it'll fail (or something like that) since it won't be able to bind it. I assume returning this should fix it though :  new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0)

Comment: I've tried this, but the BindIPEndPoint1 method is never called.