# Obtaining destination ip address in Powershell (Invoke-WebRequest)

Tags: powershell, tcp, ip

I'm writing script for automation of TCP connections and I have a question. Is there an option to get destination IP address, when you call (for example):

```
Invoke-WebRequest google.com
```

Problem is, when I call this command, destination IP address is always different, so I can't use command like ''test-connection''. I would like to hear further explanation. I know that Google has multiple public addresses, but why are they different when I call `Invoke-WebRequest`, or `Test-Connection`?

Example:

1.
[Destination IP from wireshark capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqMRx.png)

2.
IP address from `Test-Connection` command:
 google.com      172.217.18.78

Greetings

Comment: Didn't find a way to get it from Invoke-WebRequest, but you might use the underlying .Net-Libraries to get them. See for instance this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655713/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-server-that-httpwebrequest-connected-to

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Google has a *huge* userbase. They want to be reachable via multiple addresses, as that provides robust connections and some load balancing too. The technique is called [DNS Round Robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS). In case one of the multiple IP addresses doesn't work, most modern browsers will [automatically try and use](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/10927) other addresses.

If you would like to test a connection to particular IP, you could do a name lookup and pick one of the results. Like so,

```
# Get a list of all Google IPs
$googles = [Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("www.google.com")
# Use IP address for the 1st entry
test-connection $googles[0].IPAddressToString
```

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful! But i am still wondering, for example if you call "Invoke-WebRequest www.google.com", when you call this command it connects on certain DNS adress, right ? And i would like to obtain that specific address which has been reached. How would i pick that specific adress out of them all?

Comment: @booyah the list that this returns is iterated over by your browser, there's no reliable way to know which one it will choose, you can always select an IP, then run `Test-Connection` against the IP instead of the hostname?

Comment: @booyah Please explain with more details why are you interested in specific Google's address. My [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)-sense is tingling.

Comment: @vonPryz I want to write a script, that analyzes TCP traffic with tshark. So at the start, i close all unwanted processes which i can which have establised internet connection (you can't shutdown for example svchost.exe or explorer.exe), so there is clean capture of traffic. Than i start tshark and after that i call ''Invoke-WebRequest'' for ceratin website and at the end i also want to display Wireshark filter to filter out any irelatable captures, which you can't shut down (from svchost, explorer etc..). So i would to like to display filter (ip.src==my_ip and ip.dst==destination_ip).

Comment: @ConnorLSW Thanks, this is also very helpful. The catch is that command ''Invoke-WebRequest'' "chooses" the address, right ? After that command computer should know that address, that i would like to obtain. What i am doing  is explained in other comment.

Comment: @booyah Well, it depends. Most applications will be like "OS, please get me a TCP connection to google.com" whilst some may ask explicit addres like "OS, please get me a TCP connection to 192.0.2.1". It's hard to say from outside what actually happens. There are tools like Netmon and Message Analyzer that will record process ID in Windows too, so one can map application to TCP connection. Wireshark doesn't AFAIK support this.

Comment: @vonPryz Thanks for the help !

Comment: What difference does it make what all of the ip addresses they may serve their domain from? When you `Invoke-WebRequest` and get some answer, how do you check what remote ip address just served you?